# How to find a latest date from csv file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a csv files which has data. Every week I upload csv file to populate database. csv file has a column called pulished_date. I want to get a last published_date whenever I upload a csv file.

Example If I uploaded csv file on 5th may to 12th may then again ff I uploaded csv file on 20th June then last published date should be 13th may not the date when I upload new csv file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Simply store the the published_date value in a table column, and then query the maximum value from that column when you want to know the latest.

```
MyModel.maximum(:published_date)
```

Comment: Problem is I have 3 different section and I want to calculate dates for them. And  on next csv upload I want to update their dates with week after date.

Comment: How are sections defined.  Also, you say there's a published_date clumn in the CSVs, but it sounds like that's not actually what you care about, but week following the date uploaded.  Is that right, and if so, then what day does each week start on?

Comment: Now its little different. I have start_date and end_date in my table. start_date will be file upload date. Next time when i will upload a file that should become a start_date. And I have to track a published_date column in csv file based on product for start and end date.